# Algorithm challenge to merge sets

Tags: algorithm, matlab, linear-algebra

Given n sets of numbers. Each set contains some numbers from 1 to 100. How to select sets to merge into the longest set under a special rule, only two non-overlapping sets can merge. [1,2,3] can merge with [4,5] but not [3,4]. What will be an efficient algorithm to merge into the longest set.

My first attempt is to form an n by n matrix. Each row/column represents a set. Entry(i,j) equals to 1 if two sets overlap, entry(i,i) stores the length of set i. Then the questions becomes can we perform row and column operations at the same time to create a diagonal sub-matrix on top left corner whose trace is as large as possible.

However, I got stuck in how to efficiently perform row and column operations to form such a diagonal sub-matrix on top left corner.

Comment: Can you please post first what your own attempt is to solve it? then we can help you with specific problems you have.

Comment: Have you seen Maximum Coverage Problem ? Your question sounds similar https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_coverage_problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments (maximum coverage problem) you have a NP-hart problem. Luckily, matlab offers solvers for integer linear programming.

So we try to reduce the problem to the form:

```
min f*x subject to Ax<=b , 0<=x
```

There are n sets, we can encode a set as a vector of 0s and 1s. For example `(1,1,1,0,0,...)` would represent `{1,2,3}` and `(0,0,1,1,0,0...)` - `{3,4}`.

Every column of `A` represents a set. `A(i,j)=1` means that the `i`-th element is in the `j`-th set, `A(i,j)=0` means that the `i`-th element is not in the `j`-th set.

Now, `x` represents the sets we select: if `x_j=1` than the set `j` is selected, if `x_j=0` - than not selected!

As every element must be at most in one set, we choose `b=(1, 1, 1, ..., 1)`: If we take two sets which contain the `i`-th element, than the `i`-th element of `(Ax)` would be at least 2.

The only question left is what is `f`? We try to maximize the number of elements in the union, so we choose `f_j=-|set_j|` (minus owing to min<->max conversion), with `|set_j|` - number of elements in the `j`-th set.

Putting it all in matlab we get:

```
f=-sum(A)
xopt=intlinprog(f.',1:n,A,ones(m,1),[],[],zeros(n,1),ones(n,1))
```

- `f.'` - cost function as column
- `1:n` - all `n` elements of `x` are integers
- `A` - encodes `n` sets
- `ones(m,1)` - `b=(1,1,1...)`, there are `m=100` elements
- `[],[]` - there are no constrains of the form `Aeq*x=beq`
- `zeros(n,1), 0<=x` must hold
- `ones(n,1), x<=1` follows already from others constrains, but maybe it will help the solver a little bit

Answer (score 0):

You can represent sets as bit fields.  A bitwise and operation yielding zero would indicate non-overlapping sets.  Depending on the width of the underlying data type, you may need to perform multiple and operations.  For example, with a 64 bit machine word size, I'd need two words to cover 1 to 100 as a bit field.